# UITableView: Changing one cell's height constraint after table is constructed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I might be wanting a strange thing, but the task is to stretch last cell in UITableView to fill the rest space. So in case table will only have few cells, then the last one will match it's height to the rest until screen bottom.

To achieve this, I included height constraint in the last cell's xib. 
I can calculate proper height and set the constant, but it does not matter what I do afterwards - `setNeedsDisplay()`, `setNeedsLayout()`, `reloadData()`, `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths()` etc. - the cell height is not changed.

Only when I call the update code second time, layout is adjusted.

Any hints how to force update the cell immediately?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the following implemented (viewDidLoad is fine).

```
var estimatedRowHeight = 80 (for example)

// Set automatic dimension on row height.
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

// Set estimated row height.
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = estimatedRowHeight
```

Remove the height constraint and then call your resize with either the `reloadData`, or `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths()`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following method? Where you check for the last indexPath.row and put a different height that you calculate.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```